# How to export database to OWL file in Stardog?

Tags: rdf, owl, stardog

http://stardog.com/docs/using/#export shows help for exporting a db into "ttl" file.
I wanted to export the database into some common formats like "rdf" or "owl".

How to export to OWL format or RDF format?

Comment: OWL files are RDF files (and by RDF, you presumably mean RDF/XML). OWL is the name of an [ontology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29) language, and is used to define classes and properties (amongst other things). Unless you *only* store ontologies in your database, exporting all data to an OWL file doesn't make sense, or should be done using a SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` query that only selects OWL concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command should do the job (export in RDF/XML, classical RDF):

```
$ stardog export -c myDatabase --format RDFXML myDatabase_output.rdf
```

Comment: This has changed recently, it is now: `stardog data export <dbName> --format RDFXML -u <username> -p <password> myDatabase_output.rdf`